# Spring Cloud Gateway on App engine is not routing the requests to downstream services

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to deploy a simple microservice application (Spring boot) in GAE. The application has 3 services -
1. Discovery Service
2. Spring Cloud Gateway
3. Customer service

I am trying to call an API through API gateway. This works fine in local machine but getting 404 in GAE hosted application.

The URL I am using is -  **https://Gateway-url/customer-service/version**
And corresponding YAML config is :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:     
      routes:
      -id: customer-service
        uri: https://XXXXXX.customer-service.appspot.com/
        predicates:
        - Path=/customer-service/**       
        filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
```

The URI configured in above code snippet is - target URL of GAE service.

So When I hit the **https://Gateway-url/customer-service/version** url in browser, I am getting 404 error but it works if I hit the direct url **https://customer-service-url/version**

When I changed the API Gateway configuration in the local environment, (change uri to cloud based service uri), the issue is reproducible. So I am thinking that Gateway is not able to route the requests to App Engine Service target URL.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you check the handlers from the app.yaml or post them maybe the issue lies with the way is handling the requests.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue. The issue is with the host header. Spring gateway put HOST header (value is gateway application host) in the request. So instead of making a call to customer-service, it was trying to call API on gateway application. As gateway application doesn’t have /version endpoint, it was throwing 404 error.

In spring gateway,  I applied RemoveRequestHeader filter to remove HOST header and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the url that you are using in the configuration file to route your requests.
According to google cloud documentation, to call from one service to another you should use a endpoint like this

```
https://VERSION_ID-dot-SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com
```

As yo can see here 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/communicating-between-services

And it seems that the url that you are using doesn't fit int this.

Anyway I think that in a serverless environment such as app engine the best option to perform service discovery and to route requests via gateway is using the services provided by google. In case of service discovery it is done automatically and if you want a gateway you can use google cloud endpoints that have a greate integration with app engine. Because this is the gateway intended to use with these applications

Comment: Thanks JArgente. I am using url in the same format. As I mentioned earlier, I am able to access url (customer-service) from browser, but the same url when configured in the gateway route configuration, it is not working.